# How to limit the number of threads in Python with Pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using Pytesseract to run Tesseract v5.0.1.  I get worse character recognition when I run it on my Windows desktop PC than than when I run it on my Windows Surface Pro with the same image.  On the Surface Pro the image I am processing takes 24 seconds to process while on my desktop PC it only takes 4 seconds.  I am assuming that more threads are being used when it is being processed on my desktop PC.  I would like to limit the number of threads on the desktop PC to see if this improves character recognition.  I have tried the following code and it does not appear to change anything as it still processes in 4 seconds:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"]= '1'
os.environ["OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"] = '1'
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = '1'
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = '1'
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = '1'
os.environ["PAPERLESS_AVX2_AVAILABLE"]="false"
os.environ["OCR_THREADS"] = '1'
```

The desktop PC has a AMD FX-8320 Eight-Core Processor with 4 cores and 8 logical processors.  The Surface Pro has a Intel Core m3-7Y30 CPU with 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

Answer (score 0):

I add this in the beginning of my code and it works for me:

```
os.environ['OMP_THREAD_LIMIT'] = '1'
```

Comment: This is what I tried and it did not have any effect.